# Retrieving the page number from the document in question-answering task [LangChain]

Tags: pdf, openai-api, langchain, nlp-question-answering, large-language-model

I am building a question-answer app using LangChain. Following the numerous tutorials on web, I was not able to come across of extracting the page number of the relevant answer that is being generated given the fact that I have split the texts from a pdf document using `CharacterTextSplitter` function which results in chunks of the texts based on some mathematical inference. I wanted to know, if I could retrieve from what page is the relevant answer being retrieved from after chunking the answers?

I tried some tutorials in which the pdf document is loader using `langchain.document_loaders.PyPDFLoader` function and loads the textual data as many as number of pages. After passing that textual data through vector embeddings and QA chains followed by query input, it is able to generate the relevant answers with page number. But in my case, I am not able to extract the page number as I had split the textual data into chunks.

Comment: it depends on how you are building your prompt, and also it's worth to check the metadata of `PyPDFLoader`

Answer (score 1):

this could be a way to achieve it.

1. build a loader

```
# read a pdf and answers question on it
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

loader = PyPDFLoader("lobel-frog-toad.pdf")
pages = loader.load_and_split()
# check the metadata
pg_no=66
print(f"Content:\n {pages[pg_no].page_content} \n metadata:\n {pages[pg_no].metadata}")
```

output:

```
Content:
 “Oh, yes there will,” said Frog,
“because I have sent you a letter.”
“You have?” said Toad.
“What did you write in the letter?”
Frog said, “I wrote ‘Dear Toad, I am
glad that you are my best friend.
Your best friend, Frog.’”
“Oh,” said Toad, “that makes a very
good letter.”
Then Frog and Toad went out onto
the front porch to wait for the mail.
They sat there, feeling happy
together. 
 metadata:
 {'source': 'lobel-frog-toad.pdf', 'page': 82}
```

create an embedding:

```
# create the open-source embedding function
embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

# load it into Chroma
db = Chroma.from_documents(pages, embedding_function)
```

build the chain and retrieval, comments added with code

```
import os
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains.combine_documents.stuff import StuffDocumentsChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import create_qa_with_sources_chain

# open AI
OPENAI_key='sk-your_openAI_key'

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = OPENAI_key


llm_src = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613")

qa_chain = create_qa_with_sources_chain(llm_src)

doc_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template="Content: {page_content}\nSource: {source} \n Page:{page}", # look at the prompt does have page#
    input_variables=["page_content", "source","page"],
)

final_qa_chain = StuffDocumentsChain(
    llm_chain=qa_chain, 
    document_variable_name='context',
    document_prompt=doc_prompt,
)
retrieval_qa = RetrievalQA(
    retriever=db.as_retriever(),
    combine_documents_chain=final_qa_chain
)

query = "why Frog sent letter to Todd?"

answer_1=retrieval_qa.run(query)
```

when print the `answer_1` will get a response as

```
'{\n  "answer": "Frog sent a letter to Toad because Frog considered Toad to be his best friend and wanted to express his appreciation for their friendship.",\n  "sources": ["lobel-frog-toad.pdf (Page 82)"]\n}'
```

Comment: I have used `langchain.text_splitter.CharacterTextSplitter` after extracting all the texts from the pdf documents (using `CharacterTextSplitter.split_text`) which split the documents into chunks. The metadata gets lost there. Is there any way I can retrieve the metadata?

Comment: would like to see your pdf and code. if metadata is lost, then need to add using some code logic.

Comment: In my case, I had to add a Split each page content to avoid error on maximum context of LLM.
        `for i, page in enumerate(documents):
            page_split = text_splitter.split_documents(page)`

Answer (score 0):

I found that using this looping for loop I had to split each page and then assign the metadata.

```html
    for reader in pdf_docs:
        splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
            separators=["\\n\\n", "\\n", " ", ""],
            chunk_size=1000,
            chunk_overlap=200,
            length_function=len)
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(reader)

        for i, page in enumerate(pdf_reader.pages):
            text = page.extract_text()
            text_temp = []
            for page_text in text.split('\x0c'):
                text_temp += splitter.split_text(page_text)
            for j, chunk in enumerate(text_temp):
                metadatas.append({'source': reader.name, 'page': i+1, 'index': j+1})
            pages = text_by_loaders_page.append(text_temp)

# test
    display_page(6, 1, text_by_loaders_page, metadatas)
```

Display page is a function I added that is follows:

```html
def display_page(page_num, chunk_index, text_by_loaders_page, metadata):
    if metadata is None:
        st.write(f"No metadata found for page {page_num} and index {chunk_index}")
        return
    text_chunk = text_by_loaders_page[metadata['index']] if 'index' in metadata else ""
    st.write(f"Content:\n{text_chunk}\nMetadata:\nSource: {metadata['source']}, Page: {metadata['page']}, Index: {metadata['index']}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).